# How to render indentation with erb in Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, partials, renderpartial

So I have a partial which gets a parameter and lists its properties:

```
<% if entry %>
  {
  <%= render partial: 'user_data', locals: {entry: entry} %>            
  }
<% end %>
```

The _user_data.html.erb:

```
<% if entry.name != nil %>
  name: <%= entry.name %>
  entry number: <%= entry.number %>  
  user: <%= entry.user %>
<% else %>
  name: nil
  entry number: nil
  user: nil
<% end %>
```

What I get is:

```
  {
    name: nil
entry number: nil
user: nil
  }
```

How could I indent them properly? Why is it happening at all?

Comment: do you have to return a json or html?

Comment: Looks like OP wants to render HTML but that looks like JSON. Assumnig because of `.html.erb`.

Comment: That's just pure view formatting preference, nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Do you want to just render formatted output in HTML? or return a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just formatted HTML output, try using `<pre>` tag:

```
<% if entry %>
  <pre>
  {
    <% if entry.name != nil %>
      name: <%= entry.name %>
      entry number: <%= entry.number %>  
      user: <%= entry.user %>
    <% else %>
      name: nil
      entry number: nil
      user: nil
    <% end %>
  }
  </pre>
<% end %>
```

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1vaweqku/1/)